# Hide pivotItem from settings in localstorage

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I want to let user choose in settings which pivotItems wants to have shown and which not. I made settings page and [used this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) I really like it and now I am looking for easy way how to applied this. I tried to find if pivotItem has some property for this (Visible) but I found just that I must use code and remove it from collection. Is it really true? There is no way how can I do it in xaml (like binding true/false value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in xaml i would create a list of Items in a viewmodel and bind a subset of this list that is selected to your pivot.

the key is thus not to hide certain items but just not binding them.

Are you using mvvm?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it would be solution for what I wrote. But now I think that I just must use code-way because I am downloading that data and It would be best that if user don´t want to see it It don´t download too.